Read sort and extract file name from HMTL raw text list
I have a file in raw HTML raw text format. It contains a list of files with thousands of lines.
The list looks like this:
<html>
<head><title>Index of /</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Index of /</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="9999920122022-SP.xml">9999920122022-SP.xml</a>                               20-Dec-2022 15:46                2652
<a href="10000020122022-PR.xml">10000020122022-PR.xml</a>                              20-Dec-2022 15:47               74861
<a href="10000120122022-SC.xml">10000120122022-SC.xml</a>                              20-Dec-2022 16:03              160717
<a href="10000220122022-SC.xml">10000220122022-SC.xml</a>                              20-Dec-2022 16:03              160717
<a href="10852508042023-ESP%3FRITO%20SANTO-ES.xml">10852508042023-ESP?RITO SANTO-ES.xml</a>               08-Apr-2023 22:59              379563
<a href="10000320122022-MG.xml">10000320122022-MG.xml</a>                              20-Dec-2022 16:21             8122831
<a href="11054812072023-S%3FO%20PAULO-SP.xml">11054812072023-S?O PAULO-SP.xml</a>                    12-Jul-2023 21:52              690879
<a href="10170411012023-MATO%20GROSSO-MT.xml">10170411012023-MATO GROSSO-MT.xml</a>                  11-Jan-2023 14:57             5819174
<a href="10272320012023-RIO%20DE%20JANEIRO-RJ.xml">10272320012023-RIO DE JANEIRO-RJ.xml</a>               20-Jan-2023 23:03             1000763
<a href="10000420122022-SP.xml">10000420122022-SP.xml</a>                              20-Dec-2022 17:37               11552
<a href="10000520122022-PR.xml">10000520122022-PR.xml</a>                              20-Dec-2022 17:57               33926
</pre><hr></body>
</html>


I need to find what is the newest file from this list based on the date and time columns.
To do this, I've created the following script.
#!/bin/bash

# Function to extract the date and time from the HTML line
extract_datetime() {
    line="$1"
    # Extract the date and time from the line using awk
    datetime=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3, $4}')
    # Convert the date and time to a format suitable for comparison
    date -d "$datetime" +%s
}

# Read the HTML content from a file
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    html_content=$(<"$1")
else
    echo "File not found: $1"
    exit 1
fi

newest_datetime=0
# Iterate over each line of the HTML content
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Check if the line contains an XML file
    if [[ "$line" =~ href=\"([^\"]*\.xml)\" ]]; then
        # Extract the file name and date/time from the line
        filename="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        file_datetime=$(extract_datetime "$line")
        # Compare the current file's date/time with the newest one found so far
        if (( file_datetime > newest_datetime )); then
            newest_datetime=$file_datetime
            newest_file="$filename"
        fi
    fi
done <<< "$html_content"

# Output the newest file
echo "Newest file: $newest_file"


Some files in the list may have multiple spaces in the name, which causes Awk to extract the wrong values for date and time.
As a result, the date command gives me errors like these.

date: invalid date ‘SANTO-ES.xml 08-Apr-2023’ 
date: invalid date ‘PAULO-SP.xml 12-Jul-2023’ 
date: invalid date ‘GROSSO-MT.xml 11-Jan-2023’ 
date: invalid date ‘DE JANEIRO-RJ.xml’

Now I'm having a hard time figuring out how to handle these spaces in the filenames.
Any thoughts on this?

btw, do you want what is presumably the actual filename (content between <a> and </a> - although it could be mangled ) or the url-encoded filename (href value inside the double-quotes - will need to be decoded) ?

Any of these would suffice, but I think the name between the start and end of the anchor tag <a> is better.

An apache directory index can be date reversed sorted by adding ?D=D query parameter. Same as clicking Last Modified column

By default, awk splits fields by runs of whitespace. If you care about retaining the exact spacing, you have to do more than use the default fields.
Calling awk once for every line is also inefficient.
It would be better to use an xml/html parser but assuming the file is guaranteed to have the specific format shown, it is not necessary to call date on each line as months can be converted to numbers and then the date rearranged to allow simple sort.
#!/bin/sh

if ! [ -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "File not found: $1"
    exit 1
fi

awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",a)
        for(i in a) m2i[a[i]] = sprintf("%02d",i)
    }
    /^<a href=/ {
        split($0,a,/[<>]/)
        if (a[3] ~ /[.]xml$/) {
            split($(NF-2),d,/-/)
            print d[3] m2i[d[2]] d[1] $(NF-1), a[3]
        }
    }
' "$1" |
sort -r |
awk '
    NR>1 && p1!=$1 { exit }
    { p1=$1; print substr($0,17) }
'

or with just bash:
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "File not found: $1"
    exit 1
fi

declare -A m2i
i=101
for m in Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec; do
    m2i[$m]=${i:1}
    ((++i))
done

newest_datetime=000000000000
newest_files=()
declare -n q=BASH_REMATCH
#                 1          2          3     4            5          6
re='<a href=".+">(.+)</a>\s+([0-9]{2})-(...)-([0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
        this_datetime=${q[4]}${m2i["${q[3]}"]}${q[2]}${q[5]}${q[6]}
        if [[ $this_datetime > $newest_datetime ]]; then
            newest_datetime=$this_datetime
            newest_files=("${q[1]}")
        elif [[ $this_datetime = $newest_datetime ]]; then
            newest_files+=("${q[1]}")
        fi
    fi
done <"$1"

printf '%s\n' "${newest_files[@]}"

These should both handle the case of more than one file being "newest".

Awk scripting is on another level for me. $ time ./newest_xml.sh list = real    0m24.204s
I tried with just Bash, and it works quite well. I appreciate your help.

Why don't you use the RE in bash with BASH_REMATCH array for date matching?
#!/bin/bash

# Read the HTML content from a file
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    html_content=$(<"$1")
else
    echo "File not found: $1"
    exit 1
fi

newest_datetime=0
# Iterate over each line of the HTML content
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Check if the line contains an XML file
    if [[ "$line" =~ href=\"([^\"]*\.xml)\".*\</a\>\ *([0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+) ]]; then
        # Extract the file name and date/time from the line
        filename="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        printf "filename='%s'\n" "$filename"
        file_datetime="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        # Compare the current file's date/time with the newest one found so far
        # printf "file_datetime='%s'\n" "$file_datetime"
        file_datetime=$(date -d "$file_datetime" +%s)
        # printf "file_datetime='%s'\n" "$file_datetime"
        if (( file_datetime > newest_datetime )); then
            newest_datetime=$file_datetime
            newest_file="$filename"
        fi
    fi
done <<< "$html_content"

# Output the newest file
echo "Newest file: $newest_file"

Update (much faster)
Call date is really slow. Date conversion to seconds is really not necessary because you don't need to make calculation with theses seconds (i.e. elapsed time).
So, It's just necessary to make a conversion of date format and compare strings:
From "Day-Month-Year Hour:Minutes"
To   "YearMonthDayHourMinutes"
Via a conversion from month in letters to month in digits.
#!/bin/bash

# Read the HTML content from a file
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    html_content=$(<"$1")
else
    echo "File not found: $1"
    exit 1
fi

declare -A hash_months=(
    ["Jan"]="01"
    ["Feb"]="02"
    ["Mar"]="03"
    ["Apr"]="04"
    ["May"]="05"
    ["Jun"]="06"
    ["Jul"]="07"
    ["Aug"]="08"
    ["Sep"]="09"
    ["Oct"]="10"
    ["Nov"]="11"
    ["Dec"]="12"
)

newest_datetime=0
# Iterate over each line of the HTML content
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Check if the line contains an XML file
    if [[ "$line" =~ href=\"([^\"]*\.xml)\".*\</a\>\ *([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9]+)\ ([0-9]+):([0-9]+) ]]; then
        # Extract the file name and date/time from the line
        filename="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        # printf "filename='%s'\n" "$filename"
        file_datetime="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}${hash_months[${BASH_REMATCH[3]}]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[5]}${BASH_REMATCH[6]}"
        # Compare the current file's date/time with the newest one found so far
        # printf "file_datetime='%s'\n" "$file_datetime"
        if (( file_datetime > newest_datetime )); then
            newest_datetime=$file_datetime
            newest_file="$filename"
        fi
    fi
done <<< "$html_content"

# Output the newest file
echo "Newest file: $newest_file"


Indeed, it is better to use Bash's RE.
However, as jhnc pointed out, using Awk and date for each line was not efficient.
`
$ time ./newest_xml.sh list.hml
Newest file: 13016118052024-SC.xml
real    6m17.653s
user    1m41.631s
sys     4m48.291s
`

I've updated my response with a second faster solution without the date function.

It can be done with awk multi-character field separator FS (regex):
# href=\042                      \042 *>.+> {2,}
# |--F1---|  filename          |--- Field separator 2 ---------------------------------|   date          |--- FS 3 -----|  
# <a href="9999920122022-SP.xml">9999920122022-SP.xml</a>                               20-Dec-2022 15:46                2652

time awk 'BEGIN{
    FS="href=\042|\042 *>.+> {2,}| {2,}"
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",x, " ")
    for(i in x) { m2i[x[i]] = sprintf("%02d",i) }
    }
    { 
        if($3 != ""){
        split($3,d," ")
        split(d[1], a ,"-")
        printf "%s-%s-%s %s|%s\n",a[3],m2i[a[2]],a[1],d[2],$2
    }
}' tmp.html | sort -dr | head -n1

Result for 11k lines file
2024-05-14 11:10|feeds/

real    0m0.370s
user    0m0.366s
sys     0m0.008s


It seems that using xmllint takes quite some time to finish. real    23m19.874s
And as jhnc pointed out, using Awk and date for each line is not efficient.
I guess I'll stick with jhnc's solution.
Thanks anyway.

@markfree yes, xmllint is slow compared to awk.

That's for sure. It was quite fast. For a list of more than 60k records, it took less than 2 seconds. $ time ./newest.sh list  -->  real    0m1.544s.
The field separation you proposed seems nice, but does it account for the few filenames that are not standard?

@markfree you mean this 11054812072023-S%3FO%20PAULO-SP.xml? yes, those are found without problem. The field separation splits fields on href=" and ".*> so whatever is between double quotes, \042 in octal.

Month conversion proposed by jhnc is needed for proper results. So my answer differs on the way it splits fields and in that uses less regular expression on each line.
